# Why is gson.jar is not included in the Selenium Java client releases?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, gson

I'm following an Udemy tutorial for Java/Selenium automation. I downloaded selenium for Java, extracted the jar files and added them to my build path. After going through some tutorials, I realize that the SendKeys command doesn't work. Drivers, find element and click are fine. I checked the jars that the instructor is using and one of my jars is missing which is gson 2.8. For some reason that jar file doesn't get downloaded/extracted. I tried downloading and extracting it separately, added it to my project build path and restarted eclipse, but I'm still getting the same SendKeys error. It's not an error with my code. Image of my build path below. I'm out of things to try!
[image]

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? the Gson library is used for serialization/derialization so I'd be a bit surprised if that's actually your issue.

Comment: In the question you say that Gson 2.8 is missing, whereas the screenshot shows Gson 2.7 on the _Java Build Path_.

Comment: Error: "The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type List<WebElement>"

The instructor pointed out that I should check that the correct jars are in my build path. That was the only one missing so I made a guess that that could be the reason. If that's not the issue, maybe I need to create another post.

Gson 2.7 was just what I could find at the time. I didn't think it would make a difference. Regardless, I've found 2.8 and added it to my build path and am getting the same error. Maybe it's not gson though, but I'm not sure. I followed the instructors install instructions exactly.

Comment: you just need to add https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ this jar.
All the function related to selenium will come in this jar.

Comment: @Hiten, I had already gotten the rest of my jar files from this link. Gson was the only one I downloaded separately. Any other ideas? My compiler is also already at 1.8.

Comment: did you include selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar ?
If not then include this jar and it will work.

Comment: Why do you call the method `sendKeys` with a list of web elements? If you call [`sendKeys` on a `WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-), the keys are expected as one or more strings, not a list of `WebElement`s. Please show the code where the compile error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

As per the snapshot of the *Libraries* you are provided it seems your are using **Selenium Java Client v3.14.0**.

As per the *Release Notes* of *Selenium Java Clients*:

- `v3.13.0`:

  ```
  Introduced our own JSON parser and outputter, allowing GSON to be removed from our dependencies.
  ```
- `v3.14.0`:

  ```
  Completely removed the GSON dependency. We now use reflection to try and find the class.
  ```

So, by all means **gson.x.y** library should not be present and should be completely removed.

Comment: Oh well, that's something I guess. But originally I did not have Gson in my build path as it was not downloaded with Selenium. I only added it later when I thought it was needed. I will remove it. But that still won't solve my issue with sendKeys :(

Comment: @MartinMarino Shouldn't that be a separate question along with the relevant _HTML_ and your code trials :) Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.